# Как присвоить значение двум случайным переменным?

Tags: c#, list

Не случайное значение переменной, а вполне конкретное значение (1, например) двум случайным переменным. Этих переменных может быть любое количество, и все они в разных List:

```
public List<int> param1;
public List<int> param2;
public List<int> param3;
public List<int> param4;
public List<int> param5;
public List<int> param6;
```

И этих массивов может быть сколько угодно - от двух-трех до очень много. Пока что мысли крутятся в такой области:

```
    private List<int> allParams = new List<int>();
    private List<int> change = new List<int>(); // добавить 1 если было изменение
    private int randomCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < (количество массивов с параметрами); i++){
        allParams.Add (param1 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param2 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param3 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param4 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param5 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param6 [i]);
        change.Add(0);
        change.Add(0);
        change.Add(0);
        change.Add(0);
        change.Add(0);
        change.Add(0);
        }

for (int i = 0; i < allParams.Count; i++)
for (int k = 0; k < change.Count; k++){
if (randomCounter < 2){
allParams[(Random(i)] = 1;
randomCounter++;
if (allParams[i] == 1)
change[k] = i;
allParams[(Random(i)] = 1;
randomCounter++;
if (change[k] == 1){
randomCounter--;
allParams[(Random(i)] = 1; // тут можно сделать функцию, которая будет работать по кругу,
randomCounter++;    // пока не найдет параметр, который можно изменить
    }
    }

     }
```

Но как-то это все громоздко... Плюс индекс с рандомом так не работают. Вообще, наверняка есть решение намного проще, но не могу придумать

Comment: Если вы хотите случайно выбирать переменную из нескольких, почему бы не положить эти несколько переменных в список?

Comment: @VladD Вот тут я это делаю `for (int i = 0; i < (количество массивов с параметрами); i++){
        allParams.Add (param1 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param2 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param3 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param4 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param5 [i]);
        allParams.Add (param6 [i]);`    , а что дальше - не могу придумать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, у вас есть несколько массивов, и вы хотите выбрать *два элемента* из них случайным образом. Если суммарная длина массивов `N`, это всё равно, что выбрать случайным образом два разных числа от 0 до `N - 1`.

Выбор таких чисел — простая штука:

```
static Random r = new Random();
```

```
int first = r.Next(N);
int second = r.Next(N - 1);
if (second >= first)
    second += 1;
```

Теперь нам нужно подсчитать `N`, и выбрать число по «общему» индексу в нескольких массивах. Для этого лучше их свести в общий массив:

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>()
{
    param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6
};

int N = listOfLists.Sum(l => l.Count);
```

Ну и нахождение по индексу:

```
void SetByTotalIndex(int idx, int value)
{
    foreach (var list in listOfLists)
    {
        if (idx < list.Count)
        {
            list[idx] = value;
            return;
        }
        idx -= list.Count;
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще вариант, создаю небольшую функцию:

```
void EqualsRandomCounter(int maxCounter){
    randomCounterA = Random.Range (0, maxCounter);
    randomCounterB = Random.Range (0, maxCounter);
    if (stopRandomCounterB == false && randomCounterB == randomCounterA) {
        randomCounterB = Random.Range (0, maxCounter);
        EqualsRandomCounter (maxCounter);
    }
    else
        stopRandomCounterB = true;
}
```

Уверен где-то на 90%, что работает) Запускал раз 20 со значениями `maxCounter  = 2`, ни разу не выдал одинаковый `randomCounterA` и `randomCounterB`. Ну а дальше можно пользоваться так:

```
if (stopRandomCounter == 0) {param1 = 0};
```

Ну и так с любыми значениями. Единственное, все эти `if` нужно вручную писать